# Automatic dynamic selection of playback speed

Tags: webvideos

*I joined this site because this seemed to be where my question would be on topic the most. Sorry if I was wrong in my judgement.*

A lot of people watch videos (e.g. recorded talks or lectures) at higher speed than original. E.g., websites like Youtube allow viewers to select up to 2x playback speed.

I do this too and notice that I end up adjusting the speed a lot. For example, some people have large variations in talking speed over time. Any fixed playback speed ends up being to slow for some parts and too fast for others.

Are there tools/algorithms (specifically geared to lectures/people talking) that adjust the playback speed (or, equivalently, compress the time-dimension of a video) automatically and dynamically?

If there are not, do you think this is a good idea? (And if yes, let's do it!)

Comment: I think this is actually off-topic because your question is more about consuming videos, not producing videos. Besides, I'm pretty sure no such tools/algorithms exist. I recommend to accept that some parts are a bit slower. Just relax.

Comment: It's related to producing videos in that the problem is equivalent to "automatic video editing that adjusts speed". A closely related problem is to "automatically cut out parts of a video where nothing happens". Imagine videos could be edited automatically (and perhaps on-the-spot in the way a viewer likes). Wouldn't that be good?

Answer (score 0):

Might be relevant for your question:
https://github.com/nevoit/Dynamic-Adjustment-of-Playback-Speed

However, it works only with video subtitles and assumes the subtitles are synchronized to the video.